# Why does my Recent Posts box's text overflow?

Tags: html, css

Why does my Recent Posts box's text overflow? And how can I make it not, so that it basically has word wrap?

Heres the site where I'm having the problem: http://www.prime.programming-designs.com/test_forum/

Comment: Please show the relevant HTML code here - otherwise this question will become useless to future generations once the problem is solved. Thanks!

Comment: @CyanPrime I don't see the issue, so you have appear to have changed your test to include icktoofay's suggestion, illustrating Pekka's point. Please include relevant code in your question :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no word boundary, so it will not wrap. To fix the overflow, though, add this CSS property somewhere:

```
overflow: hidden;
```

Comment: how do I create a word boundery?

Comment: @CyanPrime: By word boundary, I mean space or any other character that starts or ends a word.